`[File]` is stringified to `[object File]`
I am writing a file selection form that each time a file is selected, that file will be added to the existing file array. My intention is to submit that array via the form, but after submitting, the array is stringified. I don't know how to handle it, please help me.
This is my code:
<script lang="ts">
    let selectedFiles: File[] = [];
    function handleSubmit(e: any) {
        errorCode = validate(selectedFiles);
        if (errorCode) {
            console.log(errorCode);
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
    function handleFileSelect(e: any) {
        selectedFiles = [...selectedFiles, e.target.files[0]];
    }
    // Create ref to DOM element
    let fileInput: HTMLInputElement;
</script>

<form action="?/submit" method="post" on:submit={handleSubmit}>
    <div>
        <label for="files">Click "+" to add file</label>
        <button on:click={(e) => {e.preventDefault(); fileInput.click();}}>
            <span>+</span>
        </button>
    <input type="file" accept={allowedExtensions} on:change={handleFileSelect} on:invalid={handleInvalid} bind:this={fileInput} hidden/>
        <input type="hidden" name="contest" value={contest.id} />
        <input type="hidden" name="user" value={data.user.id} />
        <input type="hidden" name="files" value={selectedFiles} />
        <p>Selected files: {getFileNames(selectedFiles).join(', ')}</p>
        <br />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-full">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>

I logged request.formData() and it came out like this:
   [Symbol(state)]: [
     {
       name: 'files',
       value: '[object File],[object File],[object File]'
     },
     { name: 'contest', value: '5bvod8teq8kh7yn' },
     { name: 'user', value: 'dvkw0v6uz31zag2' },
     { name: 'score', value: '0' }
   ]

I expected it like this:
   [Symbol(state)]: [
     { name: 'files', value: [File] },
     { name: 'files', value: [File] },
     { name: 'files', value: [File] },
     { name: 'contest', value: '5bvod8teq8kh7yn' },
     { name: 'user', value: 'dvkw0v6uz31zag2' },
     { name: 'score', value: '0' }
   ]


Not sure whay you would expect a property called files (plural of file) to have a single value. Also, JavaScript objects cannot have multiple properties with the same name!

When I make the form allow to submit multiple files at once, the request.formData is exactly what I expected. However my client does not accept that solution

When you convert an object to a string, the default value is the string [object Prototypename]. Plain objects are converted to [object Object], file objects are converted to [object File].  When you call .join() on an array of File objects, it converts them to strings and joins them.

You can't upload files using type="hidden", since that's a text input. You have to use type="file".

From this answer, seem like I cannot assign file to input like your suggestion. I've thought about manipulate this form data but seem like that behavior is probihited too.

Added SvelteKit tag, if this is incorrect, please revert.

If you create new form data, you could add the files to that, though in that case the request has to be made manually/asynchronously. When using SvelteKit, the enhance action should be used which already does this and gives access to the form data in the callback.
<script>
  function onSubmit({ formData }) {
    files.forEach(f => formData.append('files', f));
  }
</script>
<form
    method="POST"
    use:enhance={onSubmit}> ...

It is also possible to set file lists on inputs, which could be done as well.
<script>
  let submittedFileInput;

  function onSubmit() {
    const transfer = new DataTransfer();
    files.forEach(f => transfer.items.add(f));
    submittedFileInput.files = transfer.files;
  }
</script>
...
<input bind:this={submittedFileInput} style="display: none"
       name="files" type="file" multiple />

REPL

I tried the first suggestion, but it show me that
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: submit is not a function at HTMLFormElement.handle_submit.
So I follow this and modify a little bit from your suggestion.

From the first suggestion of brunnerh, I modified a little bit based on SvelteKit customising use:enhance:
<script lang="ts">
    import { enhance } from '$app/forms';
    // rest of original code.

</script>

<form action="?/submit" method="post" on:submit={handleSubmit} use:enhance={({ formData }) => {
    selectedFiles.forEach(f => formData.append('files', f));
    return async ({result, update}) => {
        await applyAction(result);
        selectedFiles = [];
        update();
    }
}}>
    <!-- rest of original code -->
</form>

Thank you so much for pointing me out my fault.
